# why does wampserver point to https://localhost as webroot?

Tags: wampserver

I have a web project in Netbeans called bigfoot. I have set up wampserver to have https. I had other websites to on my http://localhost which are running fine. However, when I run bigfoot, I get

> The requested URL /bigfoot/ was not found on this server

with https://localhost/bigfoot/ as the url.

However, when I just enter https://localhost/ as url, I get the bigfoot project's index.html file which is the homepage of bigfoot.

After hours of looking and trying for solution, I am still not sure how to fix it. If you have any ideas, that would be a great help.

Here is my httpd-ssl.conf

**

```
> #
> # This is the Apache server configuration file providing SSL support.
> # It contains the configuration directives to instruct the server how to
> # serve pages over an https connection. For detailing information about these 
> # directives see <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html>
> # 
> # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
> # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
> # consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
> #
> 
> #
> # Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG):
> # Configure one or more sources to seed the PRNG of the SSL library.
> # The seed data should be of good random quality.
> # WARNING! On some platforms /dev/random blocks if not enough entropy
> # is available. This means you then cannot use the /dev/random device
> # because it would lead to very long connection times (as long as
> # it requires to make more entropy available). But usually those
> # platforms additionally provide a /dev/urandom device which doesn't
> # block. So, if available, use this one instead. Read the mod_ssl User
> # Manual for more details.
> #
> #SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
> #SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
> #SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
> #SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512
> 
> 
> #
> # When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the 
> # standard HTTP port (see above) and to the HTTPS port
> #
> # Note: Configurations that use IPv6 but not IPv4-mapped addresses need two
> #       Listen directives: "Listen [::]:443" and "Listen 0.0.0.0:443"
> # Listen 443
> 
> ##
> ##  SSL Global Context
> ##
> ##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
> ##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
> ##
> 
> #
> #   Some MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
> # AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
> 
> #   Pass Phrase Dialog:
> #   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
> #   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is a internal
> #   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout. SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
> 
> #   Inter-Process Session Cache:
> #   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism 
> #   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
> #SSLSessionCache         "dbm:c:/Apache2/logs/ssl_scache"
> #SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:c:/Apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
> #SSLSessionCache   shmcb:c:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/logs/ssl_scache#(512000)"
> SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
> 
> #   Semaphore:
> #   Configure the path to the mutual exclusion semaphore the
> #   SSL engine uses internally for inter-process synchronization.  SSLMutex default
> 
> ##
> ## SSL Virtual Host Context
> ##
> 
> <VirtualHost _default_:443>
> 
> #   General setup for the virtual host
> #DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/htdocs" DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/footsteps" ServerName localhost:443
> #ServerAdmin admin@example.com ServerAdmin reetdipti@gmail.com
> #ErrorLog "c:/Apache2/logs/error.log" ErrorLog "c:/wamp/logs/error.log"
> #TransferLog "c:/Apache2/logs/access.log" TransferLog "c:/wamp/logs/access.log"
> 
> #   SSL Engine Switch:
> #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host. SSLEngine on
> 
> #   SSL Cipher Suite:
> #   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
> #   See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list. SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
> 
> #   Server Certificate:
> #   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
> #   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
> #   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
> #   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
> #   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
> #   ciphers, etc.)
> #SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache2/conf/server.crt"
> #SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache2/conf/server-dsa.crt" SSLCertificateFile "c:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/webserver.cert"
> 
> #   Server Private Key:
> #   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
> #   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
> #   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
> #   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
> #SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache2/conf/server.key"
> #SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache2/conf/server-dsa.key" SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/wamp/OpenSSL/certs/webserver.key"
> 
> #   Server Certificate Chain:
> #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
> #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
> #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
> #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
> #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
> #   certificate for convinience.
> #SSLCertificateChainFile "c:/Apache2/conf/server-ca.crt"
> 
> #   Certificate Authority (CA):
> #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
> #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
> #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
> #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
> #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
> #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
> #SSLCACertificatePath "c:/Apache2/conf/ssl.crt"
> #SSLCACertificateFile "c:/Apache2/conf/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt"
> 
> #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
> #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
> #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
> #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
> #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
> #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
> #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
> #SSLCARevocationPath "c:/Apache2/conf/ssl.crl"
> #SSLCARevocationFile "c:/Apache2/conf/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl"
> #SSLCARevocationFile "c:/wamp/OpenSSL/crl"
> 
> #   Client Authentication (Type):
> #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
> #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
> #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
> #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
> #SSLVerifyClient require
> #SSLVerifyDepth  10
> 
> #   Access Control:
> #   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
> #   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
> #   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
> #   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
> #   for more details.
> #<Location />
> #SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
> #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
> #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
> #            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
> #            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
> #           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
> #</Location>
> 
> #   SSL Engine Options:
> #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
> #   o FakeBasicAuth:
> #     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
> #     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
> #     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
> #     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
> #     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
> #   o ExportCertData:
> #     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
> #     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
> #     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
> #     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
> #     into CGI scripts.
> #   o StdEnvVars:
> #     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
> #     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
> #     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
> #     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
> #     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
> #   o StrictRequire:
> #     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
> #     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
> #     and no other module can change it.
> #   o OptRenegotiate:
> #     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
> #     directives are used in per-directory context. 
> #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
>     SSLOptions +StdEnvVars </FilesMatch>
> #<Directory "c:/Apache2/cgi-bin"> <Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
>     SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
>     AllowOverride All
>     Order allow,deny
>     allow from all     </Directory>
> 
> #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
> #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
> #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
> #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
> #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
> #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
> #     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
> #     SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
> #     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
> #     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
> #     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
> #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
> #     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
> #     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
> #     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
> #     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
> #     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
> #     works correctly. 
> #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
> #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
> #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
> #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
> #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
> #   "force-response-1.0" for this. BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
>          nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
>          downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
> 
> #   Per-Server Logging:
> #   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
> #   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
> #CustomLog "c:/Apache2/logs/ssl_request.log" \
> #          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b" CustomLog "c:/wamp/logs/ssl_request.log" \
>           "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
> 
> </VirtualHost>
```

**

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
    #
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you had better show us your Virtual Host definitions `httpd-vhosts.conf` and also your `httpd-ssl.conf`it sounds like you have got something a bit scrambled

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have included httpd-vhosts.conf and httpd-ssl.conf on my question too now. Thank you for looking for the problem.